# Double trapezium-like shape

Tags: css

[image]

I am busting my head with getting this double trapezium like shape on a webpage. The CSS class seen below creates a trapezium that could be duplicated and rotaded, I'm however insure how to expand it to the full width of the browser and make it responsive.

```
.warpedbanner {
    border-right: 150px solid red;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
    height: 4em;
    width: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check [LINK](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) for an shape.

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 15%, 100% 84%, 50% 100%, 0 85%, 0 18%);
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**The above snippet will work in chrome but not in FireFox. Snippet which is working in both browser is given below**

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-clip-path: url("#clipping");
  clip-path: url("#clipping");
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<svg width='0' height='0'>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clipping" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <polygon points="0 0.25, 0.5 0, 1 0.25,  1 0.75, 0.5 1,0 0.75"  />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: `clip-path` is experimental and has mixed support

Comment: @j08691 Like browser compatibility ?

Comment: @j08691 Now is it okay ?

Comment: @WesselVanderPlas Thanks for accepting the answer. It will greatly help others. Can you please upvote also ?